Blender 4.1 Geometry Proximity Part of the Target Mesh Coming close to Effector Mesh
Why did some parts of the target mesh coming up to the effector mesh when they get closer to each other like this?

Geometry Nodes setup:

I want it to be fully down like a bowl or satellite dish. How to solve that problem?
Blend File:


try this:

result:

tbh i don't know what you want to achieve with a rgb curve node from a single value (distance) which makes less sense. Or it is higher math i don't understand. I changed the map range node values a bit, hope it helps.

If you push down the sphere further it will still push the middle faces upward. I'm new to geometry nodes and just following a tutorial on youtube that showing to use that color ramp node and I added rgb curve node just for testing.
